# Using reduce array method to sum up (increment) records properties results with an undefined error

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I found tons of questions related to this issue, but still couldn't figure out what's wrong with my code using `.reduce()` array method.

Consider this simple toy data:

```js
const myRecords = [
  { name: "john", preferredColor: "green" },
  { name: "diana", preferredColor: "red" },
  { name: "george", preferredColor: "yellow" },
  { name: "ron", preferredColor: "green" },
  { name: "sarah", preferredColor: "red" },
  { name: "rachel", preferredColor: "red" },
  { name: "nicole", preferredColor: "yellow" },
  { name: "chris", preferredColor: "red" },
];
```

I want to summarize this data into an object that sums up each color:

```js
{ colorCount: { red: number, yellow: number, green: number } }
```

To this end, `reduce` seems a natural choice. Here's my implementation that doesn't work:

```js
// my attempt
const res = myRecords.reduce(
  (acc, person) => // reducer
    person.preferredColor === "green"
      ? (acc.colorCount.green += 1)
      : person.preferredColor === "yellow"
      ? (acc.colorCount.yellow += 1)
      : (acc.colorCount.red += 1), 
  { colorCount: { red: 0, yellow: 0, green: 0 } } // init value
);
```

But I get this error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'red')

I can't wrap my head around this. My code seems pretty straightforward. I'm not missing a `return` statement because the reducer function is an arrow function without `{}` scope. Where's the mistake?

Comment: Your reducer callback has to return `acc`

Comment: There's no way to use an arrow function *without* an explicit `return` then?

Comment: There is, but the expression in your `=>` function does not evaluate to `acc`.

Comment: I see. I would be grateful to learn how!

Comment: Well there are two things you could do: put `{ }` around the function body and include an explicit `return`, or put `( )` around the whole expression and add `, acc` at the end (inside the outer `( )` layer).  The second approach creates a "comma expression", whose value will be the thing after the last comma. Personally I would use an explicit `return` because it's much clearer.

Comment: As is usually the case with `reduce`, the code would be a lot clearer if you just used a simple loop. When you're doing `reduce` and the accumulator never changes, it's just an overcomplicated loop that's easy to get wrong (that's largely the case when the accumulator *does* change, too). `reduce` is fine for its target purpose: functional programming with predefined, reusable reducer functions. In other contexts, there's no reason to reach for it. `const res = { colorCount: { red: 0, yellow: 0, green: 0 } }; for (const person of myRecords) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: lol I was just thinking about adding a comment like "note that some well-informed people don't like `.reduce()`" :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thanks for that. Correct me if I'm wrong, but your suggestion mutates the original object. Using `reduce` lets me work immutably, which is something I strive for.

Comment: In addition, `reduce` conveys the purpose of summarizing (or reducing), and therefore is a bit more declarative than a `for` loop which is a general thing. But that's a matter of personal preference I guess.

Comment: @Emman - There is nothing about `reduce` that makes the work more immutable than a loop, and the `reduce` code in your question **does not** work immutably. It mutates the same single object being passed around. `reduce` !== immutability. If you want do work immutably, you can do that just as easily with a loop as with `reduce`. In both cases, you have to create a new object on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Emman - Re your second point about "purpose," nothing about `reduce` says anything meaningful about its purpose vs. a loop IMHO. Both can do exactly the same things, and thus you have to say in comments (or infer from the code) what the code is doing, in both cases. It's just harder when the code is harder to understand. ;-) (For what it's worth, I'm [not](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544) at all [alone](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1213077702300852224) in thinking `reduce` is hard to understand.) But you're welcome to use what you like! And happy coding! :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thank you. It's insightful to learn about other perspectives. But even if I want to adopt the "reduce-less" philosophy, I still don't know how to do it *immutably*. The alternatives, as I see them, are either `for` loop or `.forEach()`. Both mutate the original variable. However, I strongly prefer to work immutably. Any solution to this?

Comment: @Emman - Drat, I was *literally* in the process *just now* of rewording the above because I was unhappy with their tone. So apologies if the tone was off. :-) Just again to be clear, the code in the question using `reduce` does not work immutably; it modifies the object as it's passed from one iteration to the next, exactly like that code in a `for` loop would. Using `reduce` does not mean you're doing something immutably. To do it immutably (either with `reduce` or a `for` loop), you'd have to create a new object on each iteration...

Comment: ... For instance, in the body of a non-concise arrow function passed to `reduce`: `return {...acc, colorCount: {...acc.colorCount, [person.preferredColor]: acc.colorCount[person.preferredColor] + 1 } };`, or that same code but instead of `return` using `acc = ` if in the body of a `for` loop.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder -- Ah-ha. I see. I agree this gets not too readable. But circling back to the discussion about reduce vs for-loop, using a for-loop wouldn't make it much more readable, given my desire to immutability. So does it boil down to mutable == readable in this case? And you say, if so, make it a for-loop already. Am I concluding right?

Comment: @Emman - No, not in my opinion, but it *is* opinion. :-) One of my main issues with `reduce` with an inline function is that the starting point is hidden away at the end, after the code that works on it. With a loop, the starting point is right there at the start: https://pastebin.com/qyVQ7vYZ (Or with some destructuring: https://pastebin.com/PCbV7RX8 .) (My other issues with `reduce` generally is that it's too easy to get wrong -- leaving off returning the accumulator, or forgetting to provide an initial value which *seems* to work but blows up later on an empty array, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your code, and you should return the `acc` in the reduce. I created another solution version and incremented the corresponding color counter based on the `preferredColor` value. You can check it out here:

```js
const myRecords = [
  { name: "john", preferredColor: "green" },
  { name: "diana", preferredColor: "red" },
  { name: "george", preferredColor: "yellow" },
  { name: "ron", preferredColor: "green" },
  { name: "sarah", preferredColor: "red" },
  { name: "rachel", preferredColor: "red" },
  { name: "nicole", preferredColor: "yellow" },
  { name: "chris", preferredColor: "red" },
];

const result = myRecords.reduce((prev, curr) => ({
  ...prev,
  colorCount: {
    ...prev.colorCount,
    [curr.preferredColor]: prev.colorCount[curr.preferredColor] + 1
  }
}), { colorCount: { red: 0, yellow: 0, green: 0 } })

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get the result you want using the reduce method but the bellow code works.

```js
const myRecords = [
    { name: "john", preferredColor: "green" },
    { name: "diana", preferredColor: "red" },
    { name: "george", preferredColor: "yellow" },
    { name: "ron", preferredColor: "green" },
    { name: "sarah", preferredColor: "red" },
    { name: "rachel", preferredColor: "red" },
    { name: "nicole", preferredColor: "yellow" },
    { name: "chris", preferredColor: "red" },
  ];

    const result = { colorCount: { red: 0, yellow: 0, green: 0 } };

  myRecords.forEach(rec => {
    rec.preferredColor === "green"
        ? (result.colorCount.green += 1)
        : rec.preferredColor === "yellow"
        ? (result.colorCount.yellow += 1)
        : (result.colorCount.red += 1);
  });

  console.log(result);
```

Comment: *"I don't think you can get the result you want using the reduce method..."* Yes, you can, because `reduce` is really just an overcomplicated loop. Here's one way: https://pastebin.com/PCbV7RX8